# Solving the homogeneous recurrence relation $y[n]=\frac{1}{2}y[n-1]$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

We have that $y[n]-\frac{1}{2}y[n-1]=0\implies y[n]=\frac{1}{2}y[n-1]$. Observe that :
\begin{align*}
y[n+1]-y[n]&=\frac{1}{2}y[n]-\frac{1}{2}y[n-1]\\
&=\frac{1}{2}(y[n]-y[n-1])
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
y[n+2]-y[n+1]&=\frac{1}{2}y[n+1]-\frac{1}{2}y[n]\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(y[n+1]-y[n]\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{4}(y[n]-y[n-1])
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
y[n+3]-y[n+2]&=\frac{1}{2}y[n+2]-\frac{1}{2}y[n+1]\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(y[n+2]-y[n+1]\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{8}(y[n]-y[n-1])
\end{align*}
$$
\vdots
$$
$$
y[n+k]-y[n+k-1]=\frac{1}{2^{k}}(y[n]-y[n-1])
$$
I am currently stuck here and I should end up with $y[n]=A\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n$ but I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just successively insert the recursion relation i.e:
$$y[n]=1/2 y[n-1] = 1/2^2 y[n-2]=\ldots =1/2^n y[0]$$

You can reassure that this solves the recurrence relation by induction.

Comment: That's a cool way to solve it. Thank you